# ¿Cómo acceder a una propiedad del master page desde una página ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

En la "Site.master" tengo creado una barra de navegación o navbar que comienza así:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" runat="server" id="navegador" visible="false">
...
</div>
```

Como se observa, tengo puesto el atributo "visible" a "false" porque quiero que sea visible solo cuando el usuario se haya logueado. En el fichero en el que está el formulario para loguearse, "Default.aspx.cs", me gustaría cambiar esa propiedad (la de "visible") a "true" cuando el usuario se loguea correctamente, pero no puedo acceder al elemento "navegador.visible" desde ese fichero porque no es un elemento que pertenezca a "Default.aspx", sino a "Site.master"... ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿es necesario que sea un `div`? puedes usar un `Panel` y desde C# puedes acceder a sus propiedades. Mira mi respuesta.

Comment: Siendo un div con runat="server" ya se puede acceder a sus propiedades

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder acceder a las propiedades del Master debes indicarle a la página el tipo del Master para que puedas tener acceso a sus propiedadades de una manera strongly-typed.

Para esto debes usar la directiva `<%@ MasterType %>`

Por ejemplo:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster._Default" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
```

Luego de esto debes crear una propiedad pública en el codebehind del master que encapsule la propiedades que quieres modificar para que pueda ser accedida desde otra clase, en este caso desde tu página. Por ejemplo:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public bool NavegadorVisible
    {
        get { return navegador.Visible; }
        set { navegador.Visible = value; }
    }

    // o si deseas todo el div
    public HtmlGenericControl Navegador => navegador;
}
```

Luego de esto ya puedes acceder al master mediante la propiedad `Master` desde la página. Puedes hacerlo desde el codebehind o desde el aspx.

Si es desde el `.aspx` ya puedes acceder directamente. Ejemplo:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster._Default" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%
        Master.NavegadorVisible = false;
        // o
        Master.Navegador.Visible = false;
    %>
    ...
</asp:Content>
```

Si es desde el codebehind necesitarás castearlo ya que la directiva `<%@ MasterType %>` solo funciona en el aspx.

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((SiteMaster)Master).NavegadorVisible = false;
        // o
        ((SiteMaster)Master).Navegador.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias, Carlos! Puedo acceder al menú y ocultarlo acorde al login, como deseaba. Le he dado al tick de tu mensaje para que se pusiera en verde, no sé si debo hacer más para constatar la bondad de tu respuesta. Un abrazo y mil gracias!

Comment: También puedes votar positivo a esta respuesta a otras si también te ayudaron, independientemente de cual es la respuesta escogida.

Answer (score 0):

Usa un [Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel(v=vs.110).aspx):

Ejemplo:

Código ASPX:

```
<asp:Panel ID="navegador" runat=server" CssClass="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" Visible="false">
...
</asp:Panel>
```

Código C#:

```
// En tu lógica de login aplica:
Boolean = estaLogueado = false; // Ejemplo.
if (estaLogueado) {
   navegador.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Esto no soluciona el problema de acceder a la propiedad del Master desde la página

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz, tienes razón. también se puede "en teoría" buscar el control usando `FindControl`; sin embargo, no lo he intentado. Gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Hola si te refieres a llamar a un control de la MasterPage, desde otra vista. Te puedo ayudar con esto.

```
HtmlTitle tituloPagina = this.Master.FindControl("tituloPagina") as HtmlTitle;
```

"tituloPagina" : Es un elemento de la pagina maestra, así.

```
<title data-id="titulo" runat="server" id="tituloPagina"></title>
```

Llamo a ese control mediante el id, una vez tenga ese id podemos capturar o asignar valores. 
Cualquier duda puedes dejarme un mensaje.
Saludos.